# Physics Vector Problem - Airplane

Tags: trigonometry, physics, vector-analysis

Heres the question:

A plane leaves the airport in Galisto and flies $140$km at $68.0^∘$ east of north and then changes direction to fly $255$km at $48.0^∘$ south of east, after which it makes an immediate emergency landing in a pasture.

When the airport sends out a rescue crew, how far should this crew fly to go directly to this plane?

I tried using the pythagorean theorem, but he answer I got was incorrect.  So I tried finding the components of the vectors and adding them, but that didn't work either.

Here is what I tried to do, but I have no idea if I was headed down the right track.

Components of $|\overrightarrow{A}|$ are:

$140sin(68^∘)=129.806$

$140cos(68^∘)=52.4449$

$|\overrightarrow{A}|=\sqrt{\left(52.4449)^2+(129.806)^2\right)} = 140$

Components of $|\overrightarrow{B}|$ are:

$255sin(48^∘)=189.502$

$255cos(48^∘)=170.628$

$|\overrightarrow{B}|=\sqrt{\left(189.502)^2+(170.628)^2\right)} = 255$

These weren't correct, so I greatly appreciate any guidance you can offer!

Comment: Do you know the law of cosines?

Comment: @Tpofofn sort of familiar with it, but have rarely used it.

Comment: It is like the Pythagorean theorem but for general triangles.  It is ideal to use when you know two sides and the angle between them to find the third side.  In your case the two sides are your two lengths, the angle is 70 degrees.

Comment: Try 110 degree angle if you want to do the law of cosines. The vectors will work if you setup them up correctly.

Comment: @JohnHabert, Yes, of course.  Good catch... should have sketched it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the problem with vectors, we have to break the trip up into two parts, I'll call them $A$ (airport to change heading) and $B$ (change heading to emergency landing) like you did. From the picture we can see that the vector $A$ uses an angle of $68^{\circ}$ from the vertical. So $A = \langle 140\sin(68^{\circ}), 140\cos(68^{\circ})\rangle \approx \langle 129.806, 52.445\rangle$. You could also have done $A = \langle 140\cos(22^{\circ}), 140\sin(22^{\circ})\rangle$ if you wanted to work with the angle formed between $A$ and the horizontal. For vector $B$, we have the angle with the horizontal but it is below the horizontal. So the vertical component of $B$ is negative. $B = \langle 255\cos(48^{\circ}), -255\sin(48^{\circ})\rangle \approx \langle 170.628, -189.502\rangle$. The resultant is $R = A+B = \langle 300.434, -137.507\rangle$. $|R| = \sqrt{(300.434)^2+(-137.507)^2} \approx 330.220$ km. The angle they need to travel at is $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{137.507}{300.434}\right) \approx 27.24^{\circ}$ below the horizontal or south of east.

[image]